# Ubuntu 12.04.5 64bit no /usr/lib64/?

Tags: 12.04, server, libraries

I am currently trying to setup a domU on *XEN Hypervisor* based on some tutorials. My *XEN*  installed on Ubuntu 12.04.5 Server x64 bit.. (Clean install)

I can't find `/usr/lib64` only `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib32` exist..

Why is this happening since my Ubuntu are x64 bit ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is `/usr/lib64`. This changed when Ubuntu 12.04 came out.

Comment: `/usr/lib` is not `/usr/lib64`..`/usr/lib` contains the libraries of the default architecture..

Comment: @heemayl Edited.

Comment: Actually, i meant OS architecture (32 bit/64 bit) defines which libraries will be in `/usr/lib` ..but now it does not matter as they all get merged in `/usr/lib`..so `/usr/lib` is the location of all shared libraries..